# Real Analysis of Bounded Sequences in a Closed, Bounded Interval

Tags: real-analysis

A sequence is defined to be bounded provided there is a positive real number M such that |an|< M for every natural number n. I need to prove that {an} is bounded if and only if there are real numbers a and b with a < b such that {an} is a sequence in [a, b]. So far I have been unable to produce a formal proof. Please help.

Comment: Set $a = -M, b = M$, or am I misunderstanding it?

Answer (score 1):

For one direction, choose $a=-M$, $b=M$.

For the other, choose $M=\max\{|b|, |a|\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $[a,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are reals such that $a<b$.

Now, let us take $M=\max\{|a|,|b|\}$.
Then, $|a_n|<M$ as $a_n$ lies in $[a,b]$
Hence, if Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence in $[a,b]$, where $a$ and $b$ are reals such that $a<b$, then $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Conversely, let $\{a_n\}$ be a bounded sequence. Then, $|a_n|<M$ for some real $M$.

In other words, $-M<a_n<M$ for each $\{a_n\}$.
So, $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $[a,b]$, where $a=-M, b=M$

Comment: thank you for the edits. I am still new to LaTex. please bear with my incompetence.